# Common longest and shortest path in graphs

Tags: python, graph

I need a hint were to look algo ( maybe even in python )
So I have huge amount of graphs some, and I need to find common shortest and longest path for this graphs. or common parts ( shortest or longest )

Upd for more clear describing:

Before analysis graphs already have connections between nodes ? so they are already like a path.
And as result it's needed to have common possible path for all graphs depending on connections between nodes

Comment: You have multiple graphs over the same nodes and you need the common shortest and longest paths? Did I understand that correctly?

Comment: I have multiple graphs which could have same nodes  ( in common ) , but also they would have additional nodes unique for each graph

Comment: You want Spanning Trees?

Comment: Do you have cycles or negative weighted edges in your graph(s)?

Comment: acycled graph with weighted edges

Answer (score 0):

If you have graphs with the same set of nodes (V1,...,VN) (if some nodes are unique that it does not matter, you simply ignore them as they cannot be the part of any **common** path) and want to find a shortest/longest path you can proceed as follows:

1. Generate the intersection of all the graphs, that is: a graph, that has  nodes (V1,...,VN) and node Vi is connected to Vj iff in all your graphs Vi is connected to Vj. If you have adjacency matrices of each graph, it is just an element-wise multiplication of this matrices
2. Find the shortest/longest path in the resulting graph, it has a guarantee to be the shortest (between some two vertices I suppose?) /longest (common) among all of them.

Comment: ok, but how this will influence on edge weight between nodes?

Comment: @gorysko With edge weights your problem is not well-posed anymore, because there might be two common paths, one of which is shorter on one of the original graphs and one of which is shorter on another original graph. You need to define a "common weight" which is to be minimized/maximized first.